# Changing values in storage metadata in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

In my iOS app, users can upload profile pictures which are upload to the storage in Firebase. I have saved the URL of the profile pictures on to the database so I can know which URLs correspond to which users using the following code:

```
    let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    let fileRef = storageRef.child("pages/").child(UUID().uuidString + ".jpg")

    _ = fileRef.put(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL()
            let  dictionary: [String: Any] = ["UserID": uid, "PageName": self.pageTitle.text!, "PFPURL": downloadURL!, "Tags": self.tags, "Likes": [uid]]

            let reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Pages").childByAutoId()
            reference.setValue(dictionary, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                if let error = error {
                    SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "setupComplete", sender: self)
            })

        }
    }
```

However, I would like these pictures to be editable. Is it possible I can replace the image in the storageRef yet still keep the same URL? If so, how would I accomplish that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't keep the same download URL. When the photo is edited, you'll need to update the value of "PFPURL" in the database to be the new URL.